# How to set the height of parent element the same as the children?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please take a look at this:

```css
label{
   margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    float: left;
}
span{
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}

.w{
   position: relative;
   border: 1px solid red;
}

.c{
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid green;
    border-top: none;
    max-height: 200px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

ul{
     margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 0px;
}

li{
      color: #888;
    padding: 2px 15px 0px 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 2;
    font-family: IRANSans, tahoma;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<label for="name">title</label>
<span>
  <div class="w">
    <div class="c">

      <ul>
        <li>whatever</li>
        <li>whatever</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</span>
```

Now please add `height: 60px;` to `.w` element. Then you will see some content. I want to make the height of `.w` the same as `.c`. How can I do that? Noted that the height of `.c` is not contestant. Its content will be changed.

Comment: why don't you just give it the same width in your css?

Comment: The problem is `overflow: hidden` on the parent. Removing that will show the content, but hide `title`. However, having a `<div>` inside a `<span>` in the first place is bad practice, so I'd recommend a restructure.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior in CSS, you may wish to simplify the code.

Are you setting the height of `.w` and adjusting `.c` or the other way around? You say set the height of `.w` and then you say change `.w` to be the height of `.c`.

`.c` is absolute and `.w` is relative so using `.c { height: 100% }` may achieve the effect you desire.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you did wrong is putting '*block*' element into '*inline*' element. I strongly recommend you to learn about them.

When you give 'postion: ablsolute' to element, it'll go out of the html-tag flow in the page. So, with 'position relative' that you gave to parent div('.w'), the parent div start recognize it. But the other divs can not see it. So, I have this solution for your situation:

**Give 'position: relative' to your '*span*', so it also can see your *.c* block, then give 'min-height' to your *.w* block and calculate 'min-height'(to add infinite children and don't broke the code) or 'height'(to get same height with parent) for .c block. Remove borders or subtract their width. **

```css
label{
   margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 4px;
}
span{
  position:relative;
    display: block;
}

.w{
   position: relative;
   display:block;
   overflow-y: auto;
   border: 1px solid red;
   min-height: 120px;
}

.c{
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid green;
    border-top: none;
    background-color: white;
    
    min-height:calc(100% - 1px); /*Subtract border-bottom-width*/
    width: calc(100% - 2px); /* Subtract border-left/right-width*/
}

ul{
     margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 0px;
}

li{
      color: #888;
    padding: 2px 15px 0px 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 2;
    font-family: IRANSans, tahoma;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<label for="name">title</label>
<span>
  <div class="w">
    <div class="c">

      <ul>
        <li>whatever</li>
        <li>whatever</li>
        <li>whatever</li>
        <li>whatever</li>
        <li>whatever</li>
        <li>whatever</li>
        <li>whatever</li>
        <li>whatever</li>
        <li>whatever</li>
        <li>whatever</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</span>
```